# Can not install only one dictionary

Tags: libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer

I have a sample file of spell checker that I downloaded from here...

https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/tamil_spell_chek.oxt

when I try to install it, I get an error as shown in this image...

https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/spell_check_error.png

I have successfully installed other language dictionaries before. Only "Tamil" has this error. Can anyone explain the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in two of the `.xcu` files in the extension. As indicated in the error message the root element is called `compotant-data`, however this should be `component-data` (see, e.g., https://github.com/sil-car/lt/blob/4d325d8eba1e638d252772befa3fe82fe28d6acc/oxt/en_english/dict-en-20230201_lo/dictionaries.xcu for an example for English).

A `.oxt` file is actually a normal ZIP archive, so to fix this mistake you should unzip the file, locate `tmp.xcu` and `dictionaries.xcu`, then change the second line from the top and bottom to

```xml
<oor:component-data xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" oor:name="Linguistic" oor:package="org.openoffice.Office">
```

and the line at the bottom to

```xml
</oor:component-data>
```

in both files. Then you can re-zip the whole folder again, if your ZIP utility produces files with the extension `.zip` then you can just rename that to `.oxt`. Then you can install the spell checker normally:

[image]